# Allocation using Cuda with alignment

Tags: c++, memory-management, cuda

What is the most efficient way to allocate memory using cudaMallocHost() and cudaMalloc() so that the memory is aligned to a certain value.

Just like __mm_malloc where you can pass the size with the alignment as parameters.

Comment: There's an automatic alignment to at least 256 bytes if I remember correctly. Is it not enough for you needs ?

Comment: @wohlstad in somecases I actually need more that this

Comment: what do you need? [docs state](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g37d37965bfb4803b6d4e59ff26856356): "The allocated memory is suitably aligned for any kind of variable."

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and add some information about your use case and specific needs.

Comment: At least for device side, I would leave the alignment to the CUDA runtime and just use the `cudaMallocPitch` function.

Comment: @sgarizvi How is `cudaMallocPitch` relevant here?

Comment: Because [`cudaMallocPitch`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c) allocates aligned memory.

Comment: @sgarizvi "The function may pad the allocation to ensure that corresponding pointers in any given row will continue to meet the alignment requirements for coalescing as the address is updated from row to row. The pitch returned in `*pitch` by `cudaMallocPitch()` is the width in bytes of the allocation." There is no way to pass alignment to it. The pitch is something else and only an output. This API is useful for allocating multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers returned from `cudaMallocHost()` can be post-processed with a bit bigger total size for the allocation:

```
auto alignedPtr = ptrAsULL + 4096 - (ptrAsULL%4096);
```

then encapsulated like this:

```
struct AlignedCudaBuf
{
     char * ptrOriginal;
     char * ptrAligned;
     AlignedCudaBuf()
     {
        cudaMallocHost( &ptrOriginal, size + extra );
        ptrAligned = ((unsigned long long)ptrOriginal) + 4096 - (((unsigned long long)ptrOriginal)%4096);
     }

     ~AlignedCudaBuf()
     {
         if(ptrOriginal)
         {
             cudaFreeHost(ptrOriginal);
             ptrOriginal=0;
         }
     }
}
```

This does not put too much overhead unless they are frequently created/destructed (that makes CUDA-side add API latency too).

Maybe to evade accidental copies, you could use smart pointers instead of raw pointers so that the last remaining instance of AlignedCudaBuf would destroy it only once:

```
struct AlignedCudaBuf
{
     // will it be shared by multiple graphics cards & threads?
     std::shared_ptr<char> ptrOriginal;

     char * ptrAligned;
     AlignedCudaBuf()
     {


        char * tmp;
        cudaMallocHost( &tmp, size + extra );
        
        ptrAligned = ((unsigned long long)tmp) + 4096 - (((unsigned long long)tmp)%4096);

        ptrOriginal = std::shared_ptr<char>(
             tmp,
             [](char * ptr0){ cudaFreeHost(ptr0); } // custom destructor     
        );

     }

}
```

Comment: is there a reson why you chose to represent alignment as 4096? or this is just a random number

Comment: It's for page-alignment for any future pinning of regions for fast transfers between device and host. Pinned buffers go directly through pcie while non-pinned non-aligned ones require an extra copy to a pinned place before going pcie.